# Mark all transactions in a series under a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

Supposing we have the following data, can you help me write a query that marks all transactions that participate in a series with criteria:

The series start with transaction with RespCode = '57'
The series end with the first transaction with RespStatus = 'A' after the beginning of the series. In between we can have transactions with different RespCode but the RespStatus is still 'D'.

Version is SQL 2017.

These are card transactions, the RespStatus is whether the transaction is approved or declined. RespCode is the reason for the decline.

The expected result is on the image - I need to flag the transactions that are part of a series of declined transactions (RespStatus = 'D') that started with RespCode = '57'. An approved transaction (RespStatus = 'A') ends the series.

So for example, rows 20,21,22 are marked because they're all declined and the series started with RespCode = '57'.

Row 24 is not flagged because it's declined but the series does not start with RespCode = '57'.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [ID] int, [Datetime] datetime, Card varchar(23), [RespCode] varchar(25), [RespStatus] char(1) )
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( 11377422, N'2023-04-19T20:53:24', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 11823828, N'2023-04-29T00:06:48', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 12229230, N'2023-05-10T04:14:56', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 12761727, N'2023-05-23T05:49:00', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 12949136, N'2023-05-28T22:33:25', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 13336176, N'2023-06-06T00:23:11', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 13478042, N'2023-06-09T02:18:06', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 13801436, N'2023-06-18T19:55:52', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 14442178, N'2023-07-02T00:17:37', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 14583163, N'2023-07-06T22:40:14', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 14698189, N'2023-07-09T22:44:22', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 15107992, N'2023-07-18T04:20:51', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 16129455, N'2023-08-18T23:22:18', '111111XXXXXX1111', '57', 'D' ), 
( 16203188, N'2023-08-20T18:21:32', '111111XXXXXX1111', '57', 'D' ), 
( 16254102, N'2023-08-21T02:59:09', '111111XXXXXX1111', '51', 'D' ), 
( 16343718, N'2023-08-25T21:04:59', '111111XXXXXX1111', '57', 'D' ), 
( 4983081, N'2022-09-05T17:04:58', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 5621620, N'2022-10-06T18:20:53', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 5762366, N'2022-10-12T16:18:47', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 5870930, N'2022-10-17T22:01:09', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 6169728, N'2022-10-29T16:38:20', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 6300325, N'2022-11-03T19:25:42', '111111XXXXXX1111', '57', 'D' ), 
( 6405161, N'2022-11-07T15:54:50', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 6557420, N'2022-11-12T14:46:59', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 6972655, N'2022-11-26T17:23:09', '111111XXXXXX1111', '57', 'D' ), 
( 7429597, N'2022-12-11T17:24:10', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 7429817, N'2022-12-11T17:15:13', '111111XXXXXX1111', '54', 'D' ), 
( 7539293, N'2022-12-14T01:04:45', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 7650241, N'2022-12-19T18:08:22', '111111XXXXXX1111', '57', 'D' ), 
( 8386080, N'2023-01-18T17:28:29', '111111XXXXXX1111', 'N7', 'D' ), 
( 8683916, N'2023-01-26T01:28:30', '111111XXXXXX1111', '57', 'D' ), 
( 8725093, N'2023-01-28T22:41:50', '111111XXXXXX1111', '51', 'D' ), 
( 8863541, N'2023-02-01T17:33:23', '111111XXXXXX1111', '51', 'D' ), 
( 9359202, N'2023-02-16T17:13:26', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 9573895, N'2023-02-22T08:45:36', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 9708832, N'2023-02-26T00:15:45', '111111XXXXXX1111', '57', 'D' ), 
( 9931305, N'2023-03-03T17:53:16', '111111XXXXXX1111', '51', 'D' ), 
( 9985985, N'2023-03-06T17:42:56', '111111XXXXXX1111', '51', 'D' ), 
( 10245315, N'2023-03-16T04:04:34', '111111XXXXXX1111', '51', 'D' ), 
( 10345800, N'2023-03-20T19:40:11', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 10386960, N'2023-03-09T22:17:58', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 10630165, N'2023-03-26T01:18:03', '111111XXXXXX1111', '57', 'D' ), 
( 10974576, N'2023-04-05T03:12:51', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' ), 
( 11111336, N'2023-04-10T02:45:24', '111111XXXXXX1111', '00', 'A' )
```

Comment: Some expected results and your attempt would help here. Also what defines the order your transactions? The `ID`? The `datetime`? Something else?

Comment: But no expected results and the explanation is vague at best, @siggemannen . The question is still unclear, consumable data or not.

Comment: That isn't the community consensus, @ThorstenKettner : [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing) If the question is unclear, VTC it. This stops low quality answers to low quality/unclear questions. If the OP can easily clarify their question, then it'll (likely) get quickly re-opened.

Comment: @user11130446: Just like the others, I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to order the rows by date/time and then call each continuous block of 'D' a transaction? And how would you "mark" them? I am totally lost here. Please clarify. As has been said: It would help a lot did you show the expected result and explain it.

Comment: For me it's pretty clear, op wants to find islands of transactions that start by 57 and ends before the first approved one ordered by date (and ID as tiebreaker)

Comment: @siggemannen: To me it ain't so clear. It sounds like 57 merely *happens* to be the first transaction start. Maybe because it's the first row with a 'D'? Does this make the 57 the choice when looking for later "transactions"? I don't find this clear at all. And while I found this request to get closed too early, I am a bit surprised, the OP posted their request and then hasn't cared about it for almost an hour now. Maybe the idea to close it right away was not so bad after all.

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry it wasn't clear the first time. Please ask away if there's more questions. Seriously, I was in a meeting, is an hour to respond really that slow?

Comment: *"Seriously, I was in a meeting, is an hour to respond really that slow?"* We appreciate that people have things come up, but that doesn't change the interaction here. We expect a question to be *complete* when its posted. If you post an incomplete question then it's unclear, which can (and will, as you saw) attract close and down votes. There is a small expectation that users will, at least, be able to respond to comments immediately after posting which didn't occur here, as (very) shortly after posting is often when your question will have comments posted on it (at active times).

Comment: Yep, the point is that it is very common that questions arise when a request is posted. So you should not post a response and leave, but attend to it for a while instead.

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate through the rows. In SQL interation is done with recursive queries. Two steps: 1. Number all rows with `ROW_NUMBER`. 2. Loop through the rows and set the flag.

```
with numbered as
(
  select 
    [ID], [Datetime], Card, [RespCode], [RespStatus],
    row_number() over (order by datetime, id) as rn
  from #temptable
)
, marked as
(
  select
    [ID], [Datetime], Card, [RespCode], [RespStatus], rn,
    case when [RespCode] = '57' and [RespStatus] = 'D' then 1 else 0 end as flag
  from numbered
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select
    n.[ID], n.[Datetime], n.Card, n.[RespCode], n.[RespStatus], n.rn,
    case when n.[RespCode] = '57' and n.[RespStatus] = 'D' then 1 
         when n.[RespStatus] = 'A' then 0
         else m.flag
    end as flag
  from marked m
  join numbered n on n.rn = m.rn + 1
)
select [ID], [Datetime], Card, [RespCode], [RespStatus], flag
from marked
order by rn;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/byRzqUHA

Comment: Ah, using a recursive CTE. Not a bad idea, at all.

Comment: This works great. How would you change the logic if we try not to flag the first transaction in the series and only flag the subsequent transactions? As in, the requirement for a series stays the same but the first transaction in the series is not flagged?

Comment: Either do that with an additional column in the recursive CTE somehow or use `LAG` in the final query to look into the previous row to detect a range starting row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select z.*, case when respstatus <> 'A' and i = 1 then 1 else 0 end as flag
from (
  select y.*, max(case when respcode = '57' then 1 else 0 end)
              over(partition by g order by datetime) as i
  from (
    select x.*, sum(case when nrs = 'A' then 1 else 0 end)
                over(order by datetime) as g
    from (
      select t.*, lag(respstatus) over(order by datetime) as nrs
      from #temptable t
    ) x
  ) y
) z
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IH5ophlB).

Comment: That works, thanks. How would you change the logic if we try not to flag the first transaction in the series and only flag the subsequent transactions? As in, the requirement for a series stays the same but the first transaction in the series is not flagged?